# I have a .WAV file that plays when I run a macro. However, when I run a 2nd macro the .WAV file does not play

Tags: excel, vba, wav

I'm using excel VBA to run an aircraft electrical system simulation. When I start an engine i can get the .WAV file to run, however when I start the 2nd engine it doesn't. It runs if i start eng 2 first, then not when I start 1. I've tried giving the 2 macros seperate .wav files (start1.wav & start2.wav), but it still only runs the first instance.
I've used the following code, which I found on the net.

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, _
ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Function PlayWavFileAPI(sPath As String, Wait As Boolean) As Boolean
    
    If Wait Then
        'hold up follow-on code until sound complete
        sndPlaySound sPath, 0
    Else
        'continue with code run while sound is playing
        sndPlaySound sPath, 1
    End If

End Function
```

I've put the code into the engine start macro it self and also pulled it out and made it a seperate Sub (see below). either way the .WAV files only run on the first instance.

```
Sub EngRunUp1()
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = "C:\Users\srchr\Music\JetStart1.wav"
    PlayWavFileAPI sPath, False

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your expectation? `sndPlaySound` will only play one WAV file per Excel instance.

Comment: Didn't know that. So does "sndPlaySound will only play one WAV file per Excel instance" mean one wave file per executed excel macro? If so why does the other wav file not play when i run the next macro? Is there another method of running more than one wave file?

Comment: I think you got me wrong. SndPlay will play only one file at a time.

Comment: So is there a way of getting VBA to play a subsequent .WAV file? I was talking to a guy who does DJ sets and he was saying that it sounds like Excel still thinks the sound file is playing, so when I run the second macro it skips the sound file. Do you need to 'kill off' the first instance, so a second can run?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following slighlty modified code

```
Option Explicit
#If Win64 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" _
    (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
Public Declare Function sndPlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "sndPlaySoundA" _
    (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
#End If

Const SND_SYNC = &H0                ' wait for sound to play
Const SND_ASYNC = &H1               ' no wait
Const SND_NODEFAULT = &H2           ' no default sound on error
Const SND_NOSTOP = &H10             ' skip sound if another is playing
Const SND_ALIAS = &H10000           ' play system sound
Const SND_FILENAME = &H20000        ' play WAV file

Function PlayWavFileAPI(sPath As String, Wait As Boolean) As Boolean
    
    If Wait Then
        'hold up follow-on code until sound complete
        sndPlaySound sPath, SND_SYNC + SND_FILENAME
    Else
        'continue with code run while sound is playing
        sndPlaySound sPath, SND_ASYNC + SND_FILENAME
    End If

End Function

Private Sub StopSound()
    Dim Ret As Long
    Ret = sndPlaySound(vbNullString, SND_NODEFAULT)
End Sub
```

Comment: Same result i'm afraid. Still only runs on 1st instance. Tried it with the code in the main macro and as a seperate Sub.

Comment: Sorry, you are too unspecific what your problem resp. expectation is. Code is working for me fine and as expected. You probably need to show more of your code.